# Give advice for bash command not found

Tags: bash, command-not-found

When type a nonexistent command, bash show "command not found...". In ubuntu, it will give advice for which package need to be installed; In Fedora, nothing show.

So which software has this function in Fedora? I think it's not in *bash-completion.

PackageKit-command-not-found suggest by Stephen Kitt:
[image: output]

Comment: In debian, and probably Ubuntu: The package is (literally) [command-not-found](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/command-not-found)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Fedora, this functionality is provided by the `PackageKit-command-not-found` package. It adds a `/etc/profile.d/PackageKit.sh` startup script which sets up command-not-found handling. With this in place, I get for example

```
$ evolution
bash: evolution: command not found...
Install package 'evolution' to provide command 'evolution'? [N/y]
```

It only works if DBus is running and if `packagekitd` is installed.

Comment: ▶ pgrep -l package
 3316 /usr/libexec/packagekitd

Comment: I found it works depend on network, not search local cache.

Answer (score 2):

Use this command:

```
yum whatprovides '*foo'
```

where `foo` is the command you typed and is missing on your machine.

The reason for the wildcard is that `yum whatprovides` takes as argument an absolute file path.

Comment: I know this, I use "dnf provides". but it's manually.

Comment: The question is not worded very well, but it's asking *how* Ubuntu accomplishes it, not how to mimic it.