# Recommendations for packages after trying to run missing command: how does it work?

Tags: bash, apt

On some Linux distributions (... typically, the more beginner-friendly ones, like Ubuntu), if you try running a command that belongs to a package that's **not actually installed** on the system, you get a helpful message along the lines of

```
"unknown command; it is found though in [package] or [other-package]."
```

(... I don't remember the exact phrasing; I don't really have access to a system now that has it). I'd guess it's some kind of Bash + APT magic (for Ubuntu at least).

My question is... what piece of software is accomplishing this & where can I look up more docs to make it happen on systems that doesn't come with it by default? (... or, at least, where can find its "binary-name to package name" database?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it’s a combination of shell + APT “magic” (see [the spec here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/CommandNotFoundMagic)).

Bash supports a command-not-found handler: if it can’t find a command, and there’s a shell function named `command_not_found_handle`, it calls that. Typically, a package named `command-not-found` (in Debian derivatives) or [`PackageKit-command-not-found`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/354283/86440) (in Fedora and related distributions; it’s also available in Debian) provides an implementation of this handler.

The database varies. The default in Debian piggy-backs on the `apt-file` database; see [README.Debian](https://salsa.debian.org/jak/command-not-found/blob/master/debian/README.Debian) for details. The PackageKit implementations ask PackageKit for the relevant information.

Comment: ... exactly what I've been looking for; thanks a lot!!!